# Is it a good idea to put all c++ class code in header files?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mingw, cross-platform

The reason for this idea is that C ++ has a lot of dissatisfaction with cross compilers. For example, the libraries compiled by mingw and msvc cannot call each other, and c has no such problem.

So I want to put all the code into the header file. Use header files directly instead of calling dynamic libraries.

How about it?

Comment: It's certainly a good intention. Boost started out this way. But very soon you run up against "one definition rule" issues.

Comment: currently you have to recompile everything, if you put everything in the header you have to... recompile everything. What would be the advantage?

Comment: There's the beginnings of a good question here, but "why not make every library header-only?", which is effectively what you're asking, is too broad for here really. Have you researched the libraries which currently do this? Studied and read about their advantages and disadvantages? Asked their authors how it went? Same for libraries that chose _not_ to do this? Y'know, some research.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I think the problem is more with the implementation of the compiler. If every symbol is the same, there is no problem. But the implementation of the C ++ compiler is not as unified as the C compiler. I often come across some closed source libraries that do not provide mingw versions on windows. It's a headache for me because I can't compile them from source